In early universe cosmology, how can the Boltzmann equation modify the continuity equation for energy if it follows from the Einstein Equations?
I'm taking a course in cosmology and we are currently studying nonequilibrium in the early universe to learn about recombination and photon decoupling. We are now studying the Boltzmann equation through Kolb & Turner's The Early Universe. I'm curious about the consequences of the Boltzmann equation for the continuity equation of energy density.
We start with the Boltzmann equation in the form
$$E \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} - H E p \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} = C[f], \tag{1}$$
where $\tau$ is cosmic time, $p$ is the norm of spatial momentum, $E$ is the corresponding energy, $H$ is the Hubble parameter and $C[f]$ is some collision term. $f$ is the probability density in phase space. This equation is equivalent to Eqs. (5.2) and (5.5) in Kolb & Turner's book.
Now integrate the Boltzmann equation (1) over momentum space (K&T do this after dividing by $E$, but I'm keeping $E$ as it is). We get to
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} \rho}{\mathrm{d} \tau} + 3 H (P + \rho) = \frac{g}{(2\pi)^3} \int C[f] \mathrm{d}^3p, \tag{2}$$
where $g$ counts the state degeneracy (e.g. spin).
Eq. (2) is a modification of the continuity equation for energy density, which would be the same expression, but with $C[f] = 0$. However, I'm bothered by the fact that the continuity equation can be derived directly from the Einstein equations (or, equivalently, from the Friedmann equations, if you prefer). Hence, the collision equation seems at first inconsistent with the geometric assumptions that the universe is a Robertson–Walker geometry.
My first attempt at understanding this was that we started with an incorrect stress tensor, but I believe the symmetries of the Robertson–Walker geometry fix the stress tensor to be that of a perfect fluid (otherwise, we break either homogeneity or isotropy, or both). My current bet is that this could be due to the presence of many different species, each of which do not conserve energy locally by their own, but such that once all contributions are added we recover the original continuity equation for the energy density of the whole universe (not only of, say, the electron gas). Is this the case?

Your current bet is exactly correct. The Einstein equations demand energy conservation, but only for the sum of all of the species. The Boltzmann equation (using the geodesic equation) implies that energy is separately conserved for each species, unless there are interactions between them, which are encoded in the collision term.


Hence, the collision equation seems at first inconsistent with the geometric assumptions that the universe is a Robertson–Walker geometry.

It is inconsistent (not just “at first”). And it is not surprising because the universe is not a RW geometry but only RW geometry after averaging. And averaging does not commute with nonlinear function evaluation (generally $f(\bar{x})\ne \overline{f(x)}$) and components of SEM tensor are  nonlinear functions of geometry.
Energy conservation follows from EFEs of exact microscopic geometry (reflecting the motion of each particle) but it need not follow  for an averaged geometry and precise interpretation of possible discrepancy depends on the model specifics. Even in case of a single species we can have nontrivial cases where collision term would produce modification to averaged equation of state (for example via some form of clumping that does not modify the average geometry) realizing OP's first scenario. Second scenario is also possible but one should not even assume the conservation of total averaged energy for multiple species without further investigation of the specifics of averaging procedures.
